# Radio input in knockout observableArray lose check after splice

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, radio-button

Have a radio input inside an element multiplied by **knockout** foreach.

Give an **observableArray** into that foreach.

Make a function to switch two of these elements.

*html:*

```
<!-- ko foreach: boxes -->
<div>
  <!-- ko text: $data --><!-- /ko -->:
  <label><input type=radio value=apple data-bind="attr: { name: 'fruit-' + $index() }">apple</label>
  <label><input type=radio value=banana data-bind="attr: { name: 'fruit-' + $index() }">banana</label>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<button data-bind="click: switchBoxes">switch</button>
```

*js:*

```
var viewModel = function () {
    this.boxes = ko.observableArray(['First', 'Second']);

  this.switchBoxes = function () {
    this.boxes.splice(0, 2, this.boxes()[1], this.boxes()[0]);
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

*fiddle:* https://jsfiddle.net/hejdav/6dzg9hs8/17/

Now - check both radios, then switch. See? One of radios loses its check.

Any idea to prevent this?

*One strange thing: loss come only when both radios are checked.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't bound the `checked` property, the checked status is meaningless to Knockout. I had thought that simply having an observable and a `checked` binding would make Knockout keep things in shape. Not so: you seem to have found a bug.

For some reason, Knockout isn't setting up the new last item in the list correctly. I was able to correct for it by adding a call to `valueHasMutated` on the `checked`-bound observable for the last item in boxes.

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  this.boxes = ko.observableArray([{
    name: 'First',
    value: ko.observable('')
  }, {
    name: 'Second',
    value: ko.observable('')
  }]);

  this.switchBoxes = function() {
    const arr = this.boxes();

    this.boxes.splice(0, 2, arr[1], arr[0]);
    arr[1].value.valueHasMutated();
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- ko foreach: boxes -->
<div>
  <!-- ko text: name -->
  <!-- /ko -->
  (
  <!-- ko text: value -->
  <!-- /ko -->):
  <label><input type=radio value=apple data-bind="attr: { name: 'fruit-' + $index() }, checked: value">apple</label>
  <label><input type=radio value=banana data-bind="attr: { name: 'fruit-' + $index() }, checked: value">banana</label>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->

<button data-bind="click: switchBoxes">switch</button>
```

Comment: If you remove the `name` attribute binding, everything seems to work fine... strange! Could it be that for a brief moment, there are two similarly named groups in the document, clearing the last "checked" input?

Comment: That sounds very plausible.